# Mongoose/MongoDB - Sort by highest occurrence

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to sort my response based on the highest occurrence of a **postID** and within a date.

My collection structure:

```
[
  {
    "postID": "2",
    "date": "2017-04-11 21:40:52",
  },
  {
    "postID": "1",
    "date": "2017-04-11 21:40:52",
  },
  {
    "postID": "2",
    "date": "2017-04-11 21:40:52",
  },
  {
    "postID": "2",
    "date": "2017-04-11 21:40:52",
  },
]
```

So in this case, the highest occurrence is the **postID**: 2. So I want something like:

```
{
    postID: 2,
    postID: 1
}
```

Note: Remember that I need to search in between two dates as well.

Sorry if this is too obvious. I don't even know how to begin making the Mongo's/mongoose' find search.

My Stack:

- Node with mongoose
- MongoDB 3.2.5

Any input will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB aggregation framework to group on a specific property. [Mongoose has a low-level wrapper](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Aggregate) around the aggregation framework.

You can `$group` with the `postID` as the _id which will give you the unique values for each. Then you can `$sort`. You can also use `$project` to rename the property back to `postID` if you prefer:

```
Collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$postID"}},
  {$sort: {_id: -1}},
  {$project: {postID: "$_id", _id: 0}}
]);
```

Comment: Holy moly!! That worked like a charm mate. Thanks so very much.

PS: That's one hell of a username @ExplosionPills lol

Comment: Oh and - how do I do a find within this (between two dates)? I will look around but seeing that you seem to know all things, thought I may as well ask (regarding the date field in my original question)

Comment: For the filter part just add an initial `$match` pipeline step before the `$group` i.e. `{ $match: { date: { $gt: from_date, $lt: to_date } } }`